# C++: passing const as 'this' argument ... discards qualifiers involving Json

Tags: c++, json

I obtained an error while running this code:

```
for(auto &group : riskAssess.getTopList()) {
    Json::Value thisTopPositionAsJson = addTopPlayersByPosition(group);
    topPositionAsJSON.append(thisTopPositionAsJson);
}
```

I get this error on the second line of the 'for' statement:

```
error: passing 'const Json::Value' as 'this' argument of 'Json::Value& Json::Value::append(const Json::Value&)' discards qualifiers [-fpermissive]
```

I believe that the prototype of my function `addTopPlayersByPosition` is properly written, with 'const' at the right places:

```
const Json::Value addTopPlayersByPosition(const TopPlayers &thesePlayers) const;
```

`topPositionAsJSON` is a JSON object (`Json::Value`) declared as private and non-const in a class called `RiskBuilder`. The piece of code which causes the error is a function of this class.

So what is going wrong here? Is it JSON which is getting capricious?

Comment: We need to see the declaration of the function this code piece is from (and the class of `topPositionAsJSON`). I suspect that the function is `const` qualified and that `topPositionAsJSON` is from the same class as the function.

Comment: You nailed it, WorldSender. The function was declared as:void addRiskResults() const;. I removed the const and everything is fine now. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

So the problem is that `const` is being passed to members of an object. For example

```
class Foo {
  int a;
};
const Foo foo;
// foo.a is considered const aswell
```

In your example you have a function declared as

```
class RiskBuilder {
  Json::Value topPositionAsJSON;
  void addRiskResults() const;
}
void RiskBuilder::addRiskResults() const {
  // ...
  for(auto &group : riskAssess.getTopList()) {
    Json::Value thisTopPositionAsJson = addTopPlayersByPosition(group);
    // not only is *this considered const here, but also
    // this->topPositionAsJSON
    // You can't append to a const Json::Value 1)
    topPositionAsJSON.append(thisTopPositionAsJson);
  }
  // ...
}
```

1) This also explains the error:

```
error: passing 'const Json::Value' as 'this' argument of 'Json::Value& Json::Value::append(const Json::Value&)' discards qualifiers
```

You pass `this->topPositionAsJSON` as `'this'` when writing `topPositionAsJSON.append(...)` thus triggering the error

So the simple fix is to not declare the function as const:

```
class RiskBuilder {
  Json::Value topPositionAsJSON;
  void addRiskResults();
}
void RiskBuilder::addRiskResults() {
  // ...
}
```